# Amazon S3 download file method returns empty file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to download a file from an Amazon S3 bucket. The download is successful, but I get an empty file every time. I tried downloading other files to see if it was a file issue but the same thing happened. Not sure what the problem is, but this is what I'm doing:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open('AWS Account Roles.csv', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f)
```

I know this doesn't change anything, but I have tried doing it this way too:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'AWS Account Roles.csv')
```

Any help is appreciated, and thank you all!

Comment: Can you try running it through the aws cli and see if you get the same result

Comment: check permissions on the file and check if you are using the right access keys,

Comment: It would appear that your source file is empty. If you use `aws s3 ls s3://BUCKETNAME`, what is the _size_ of the object?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to download a csv file object. then you can use whatever you like to manipulate the data object or write it to a local file.

```
import io
import boto3

obj = boto3.client('s3').get_object(Bucket='BUCKET_NAME', Key='OBJECT_NAME')
data = io.StringIO(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this problem and determined why the downloaded file can be empty. The issue is that s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f) will write content to the file, but may or may not flush content to storage. Your example shows that you open the file for write-only access, but not how the content is read.

If you attempt to read this file before closing the download file, it will be empty (or partially written for large downloads). I verified this behavior with the code, which reads the download file before an after it is closed.

```
write_file = open("/tmp/temp.txt", "wb")
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_fileobj(Bucket="BUCKET", Key="KEY", Fileobj=write_file)

read_file = open("/tmp/temp.txt", "r")
assert read_file.read() == ""

write_file.close()

read_file = open("/tmp/temp.txt", "r")
assert read_file.read() == "Test Content"
```